# What are the different low-level operators in Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: operators, genetic-algorithm, low-level, genetic-programming

For my exam, I want to elaborate on different Low-level GA operators. But I found different texts says about different Low-level operators.

[Genetic Algorithms in Search, Optimization, and Machine Learning by David E. Goldberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201157675) lists

- Dominance
- Inversrion
- Intra chromosomal duplication

  Deletion

  Translocation

  Segregation

as `low-level` operators.

And lists migration, marriage restriction and segregation as `higher level population oriented operators`.

But some other texts like [Neural Networks, Fuzzy Logic and Genetic Algorithms: Synthesis and Applications by S. Rajashekaran and G.A. Vijayalksmi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8120321863) includes migration in low-level operators.

What is the difference between this `low-level` and `high-level` operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goldberg's low-level operators alter how children are formed from the parents, and the high-level operators are modifying how selection chooses the parents. Defining migration as a low-level operator does not make sense under that definition, what other examples/definitions do Rajashekaran and Vijayalksmi give?

Comment: It lists Inversion, Deletion, Dominance, Intrachromosomal duplictaion, Translocation, Segregation, Speciation, Migration, Sharing, Mating as low-level operators.

Comment: (sorry, I've been away for a while) R&V are obviously talking in a different context - AFAIK it's not a particularly standardised thing. I would personally prefer to differentiate operators by type - e.g. mutation operators and selection operators - that way it's perfectly clear what you mean.